pcap_open_live() returning address family not supported by protocol for all devices
I am trying to implement a packet sniffer using C ran on WSL with Ubuntu, and when calling pcap_open_live, for any device, returns: Couldn't open device: `pG��: socket: Address family not supported by protocol.
int main() {
    pcap_t *handle;
    pcap_if_t *alldevs;
    char errbuf[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE];

    if (pcap_findalldevs(&alldevs, errbuf) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error finding devices: %s\n", errbuf);
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Available network devices:\n");
    int i = 0;
    for (pcap_if_t *dev = alldevs; dev != NULL; dev = dev->next) {
        printf("%d. %s - %s\n", ++i, dev->name, dev->description ? dev->description : "No description available");
    }

    // Open the first available network interface for packet capture
    handle = pcap_open_live(alldevs->next->next->next, BUFSIZ, 1, 1000, errbuf);  
    if (handle == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't open device: %s\n", errbuf);
        return 1;
    }

Tried switching between all devices(see alldevs->next->next...)
Available network devices:

eth1 - No description available
any - Pseudo-device that captures on all interfaces
lo - No description available
eth0 - No description available
wifi0 - No description available
wifi1 - No description available
wifi2 - No description available
wifi3 - No description available
bluetooth-monitor - Bluetooth Linux Monitor
dbus-system - D-Bus system bus
dbus-session - D-Bus session bus


Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72622772/address-family-not-supported-by-protocol-while-using-scapy-l3socket-with-wsl help? It is about raw sockets maybe not supported in your specific setup. Similar https://superuser.com/questions/1706688/tshark-can-not-be-initiated-under-wsl-windows-subsystem-linux-socket-adress. Based on this you likely run WSL1 not WSL2.
